# Backround of my website is not changing color

Tags: html, css

So I am really new at programming (literally started yesterday lmao). So I wrote the code and everything and the backround color just doesn't want to change to black. I also have an issue where my image is not showing up on my webiste (it used to but now its only an blank square).
Thanks for answers :)

[image: The main code]

[image: image issue]

[image: .css code]

Comment: please add the code to a snippet here and dont post it in images - it will make people answering you easy life

Comment: Don't wrap the css in `style` tags if your css is in a separate file. `style` tags are only needed when you write css in the html file in the `head` section.

Comment: PLEASE, don't refer to html/css with the word "programming". Said that, good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your CSS file, in CSS file yoou write background:red; so please change that with below code.

```
<style>
body
{
  background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

For background, you need to write complete term `background-color: red;` to make it work.

For image, make sure that the image exists in the same directory as the HTML file as you are not giving any extra path in your code.

Also, I would suggest that you go through any beginner guide on youtube first so that most of your queries are answered.

Answer (score 0):

For colouring background, you need to change this:
body { background-color: red; }

And for your image issue, make sure you are entering the right path of the image.
You can also refer here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp